# How to insert data of sql server database table columns into excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

I am trying to insert all data from sql server database table into excel macros by the help of vba coding

here is my code-

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim myConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim myCommand As ADODB.Command
    Dim DB_CONNECT_STRING As String
    Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=P3A-B1YH882\SQLOPER;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI"
    Set myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING
    Set myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn
    myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT *FROM Table_1"
    myCommand.Execute
    myConn.Close

End Sub
```

my code is not running successfully, it is showing me some compile error user-defined type not defined .

plus i also don't know what to write in code to assign the macros value .
i am not sure what to do any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue with what is called "*early binding*" vs "*late binding*". There are advantages for both methods.
If you want to use "*early binding*", you have to tell the VBA compiler what things like `ADODB.Connection` are by adding a reference: In the VBA-Editor, choose `Tools->References` and set a checkmark on one of the listed Active X DataObject libraries. Probably you are missing this reference, causing the compiler error.

I give an example for both ways that should work for you - read about binding and decide which fits you better.
Note that the Connection and Command object needs to be created by you (thus the `new` in the var declaration resp the `CreateObject`), while the RecordSet object is created by the Execute method.

To get the data from the recordSet into your worksheet, the easiest way is the `Range.CopyFromRecordSet` method. As an alternative, you can loop over the recordset and do the writing manually - you can find enough examples on the internet.

```
Sub EarlyBinding()
    Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=P3A-B1YH882\SQLOPER;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI"

    Dim myConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim myCommand As New ADODB.Command
    Dim myRs As ADODB.Recordset

    myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING
    Set myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn
    myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table_1"
    Set myRs = myCommand.Execute

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset myRs 

    myConn.Close    
End Sub

Sub LateBinding()
    Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=P3A-B1YH882\SQLOPER;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI"

    Dim myConn As Object
    Dim myCommand As Object
    Dim myRs As Object

    Set myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING
    Set myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn

    myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table_1"
    Set myRs = myCommand.Execute

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset myRs 

    myConn.Close
End Sub
```